# How to implement Python websocket client/server exchange for speech recognition purpose?

Tags: websocket, python-3.6, speech-recognition, audio-streaming

I'm trying [Kaldi/Vosk](https://github.com/alphacep/vosk-server) ASR system to enable offline speech-to-text stream processing in my Python application (Python3 used for this project). First of all, audio stream (it's fetched from an Asterisk PBX channel) gets pushed to server following this code:

```
import socket
import logging
import requests

from . import ARI_URL, ARI_USERNAME, ARI_PASSWORD, APPLICATION
from .transcription import Transcriber

logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG)

LISTEN_ADDRESS = '127.0.0.1'
LISTEN_PORT = 12222


def serve(transcriber):
    #print ('\'serve\' method invoked')
    sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
    sock.bind((LISTEN_ADDRESS, LISTEN_PORT))
    while True:
        #print ('\'serve\' point 1')
        data, _ = sock.recvfrom(4096)
        #print ('\'serve\' point 2')
        payload = data[12:]
        transcriber.push(payload)


def create_external_media_channel():
    #print ('\'create_media\' method invoked')
    url = '/'.join([ARI_URL, 'ari', 'channels', 'externalMedia'])
    response = requests.post(
        url,
        auth=(ARI_USERNAME, ARI_PASSWORD),
        data={
            'app': APPLICATION,
            'external_host': '{}:{}'.format('127.0.0.1', LISTEN_PORT),
            'format': 'ulaw',
        }
    )
    logging.debug('json response: %s',response.json())
    return response.json()['id']


def destroy_external_media_channel(channel_id):
    url = '/'.join([ARI_URL, 'ari', 'channels', channel_id])
    requests.delete(url, auth=(ARI_USERNAME, ARI_PASSWORD))


#def main():
transcriber = Transcriber()
transcriber.start()

external_media_channel_id = create_external_media_channel()

try:
    serve(transcriber)
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    pass
finally:
    destroy_external_media_channel(external_media_channel_id)
    transcriber.stop()
```

It just receives media from the Asterisk channel since conversation get started. In the next I'm going to  send raw data chunks to the local Vosk server instance which is hosting the Kaldi ASR engine inside of a docker container as explained in [this user's readme](https://github.com/alphacep/vosk-asterisk). So, I need to implement data chunk stream to the Vosk server that's listening on port 2700 as a docker-featured application. That stream should be running up to the end of an ongoing phone conversation, sure. Since processing chunks is over on Vosk server, each portion of them to be reverted to the server you've seen above. There is an attempted implementation of this transcription exchange:

```
import logging

from queue import Queue
from threading import Thread
from websocket import create_connection
import websocket
import sys
import json

from .output import Output

_DONE = object()

class Transcriber:

    def __init__(self):
        
        self._queue = Queue()
        self._thread = Thread(target=self._transcribe)
        self._output = Output()
        self._ws = create_connection('ws://127.0.0.1:2700')       
        
    def start(self):
        self._thread.start()        

    def stop(self):
        self._queue.put_nowait(_DONE)
        self._thread.join()

    def push(self, data):
        self._queue.put_nowait(data)

    def _transcribe(self):
        step = 64 * 1024
        transcribe_threshold = step       
        buffer = b''
        output = '\n'
        while True:
            data = self._queue.get()
            try:
                if data == _DONE:
                    return
                buffer += data
                written = len(buffer)
                if written >= transcribe_threshold:
                    transcribed = self._do_transcription(buffer, output)
                    transcribe_threshold = written + step
                    self._output.write(transcribed)
            finally:
                self._queue.task_done()
    
    def _do_transcription(self, data, output):
        logging.debug('Sending %s to the ASR engine', len(data))
       
        self._ws.send_binary(data)
        res = self._ws.recv()       
        output += '{}\n'.format(res)
        
        logging.debug('final output: %s', output)
        return output
```

This way of implementing what I want seems cumbersome and weird also, but I haven't had pretty good experience in Python rather in other languages. Before posting this question I was looking for any relevant guides and examples, including [Python docs for websocket-client module](https://websocket-client.readthedocs.io/en/latest/). However, I believe the code I have yet is wrong and needs significant troubleshooting - it's because I see this error message every time when doing test calls via VoIP endpoint devices:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/threading.py", line 916, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/threading.py", line 864, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/transcript_demo-1.0-py3.6.egg/transcript_demo/transcription.py", line 79, in _transcribe
    transcribed = self._do_transcription(buffer, output)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/transcript_demo-1.0-py3.6.egg/transcript_demo/transcription.py", line 109, in _do_transcription
    res = self._ws.recv()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/websocket/_core.py", line 314, in recv
    opcode, data = self.recv_data()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/websocket/_core.py", line 331, in recv_data
    opcode, frame = self.recv_data_frame(control_frame)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/websocket/_core.py", line 344, in recv_data_frame
    frame = self.recv_frame()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/websocket/_core.py", line 378, in recv_frame
    return self.frame_buffer.recv_frame()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/websocket/_abnf.py", line 361, in recv_frame
    self.recv_header()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/websocket/_abnf.py", line 309, in recv_header
    header = self.recv_strict(2)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/websocket/_abnf.py", line 396, in recv_strict
    bytes_ = self.recv(min(16384, shortage))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/websocket/_core.py", line 453, in _recv
    return recv(self.sock, bufsize)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/websocket/_socket.py", line 115, in recv
    "Connection is already closed.")
websocket._exceptions.WebSocketConnectionClosedException: Connection is already closed.
```

Would you help me figure out what's an origin of trouble with websocket settings? Which implementation of them could be recommended to keep regular data flow between servers from call answer till hangup?

Comment: Hi, Haskell could you figure out the source of the problem and its probable solution?

Comment: @pierre, I folllowed an suggestion to use async implementations of websockets rather than strictly synchronized code like one in my question. Most probably, this initial approach (I picked it being just a newbie in socket programming, so it's a kind of experiment using Python) was considered profoundly wrong, thus the program didn't work properly. Now, things look (and work indeed) without those painful errors. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66469586/with-asyncio-in-python-3-code-how-can-i-restart-stop-non-blocking-websocket-i) you can find some code to see what changed exactly.